# Clarification about the definition for polynomial discriminant?

Tags: polynomials, definition, discriminant

On the wikipedia page about polynomial discriminants, it shows this definition:
$$\Delta = a_n^{2n-2}\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)^2$$
What I'm getting from this is that  $\Delta$ is obviously the discriminant, $a$ is a coefficient, $n$ is the power of the polynomial (not sure on this one), and $r$ is a root of the polynomial. However I don't understand this business with $i$ and $j$. What's with the $i<j$ under the $\prod$? Why doesn't it have an upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

The subscripts index the roots $r_i$ of the polynomial. Since we restrict to $i < j$ (which we could write as $1 \leq i < j \leq n$), this means that the product (1) runs only over pairs of *distinct* roots, and (2) counts each pair only once (as opposed to twice, for the two possible orders of two roots). For example, if $n = 3$, the pairs $(i, j)$ of integers such that $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ are $(1, 2)$, $(1, 3)$, and $(2, 3)$, and so the discriminant is
$$\Delta = a_3^4 (r_1 - r_2)^2 (r_1 - r_3)^2 (r_2 - r_3)^2 .$$

Comment: What if $n=1$? How would that work for the product?

Comment: In that case there are no admissible pairs, so the product is empty, and usually we define the empty product to be $1$ (just like we usually define the empty sum to be $0$) and hence the discriminant to be $1$. This isn't so useful, however, since we already know that degree $1$ polynomials cannot have repeated roots. Note that for $n = 2$ this coincides with what we usually call the discriminant of a quadratic.